# Switching systems

Tags: node

I originally setup my node on an RPI while awaiting new hardware. My new hardware has arrived but as the architecture is different I need to start with a clean install. What is the simplest way to to move my current node and settings to a new system? Can I simply copy the node directory over? or do I need to create a snapshot then re-import the snapshot?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to build all the software. On the new hardware, do the standard git clone .. make build-deps .. make. Then you can shut down the node on the original host, copy the node directory over to new and start up on new.

However, the better practice would be to export a snapshot from the RPI and import that snap to the new hardware and start the node. Wait for it to sync and *then* stop the RPI node.

Whatever you do, make sure you are never running two bakers nor two endorsers as you'll risk double baking/endorsing which will be a loss of rewards.